# Can't get Joomla site to work locally

Tags: php, joomla

I have a cloudaccess site on Joomla.  I would like to be able to work on the site locally.  I've downloaded the files and the database and am pretty sure I set them up correctly.  I'm using xampp and I put the site files into a folder under htdocs.  I used phpmyadmin to import the sql file. I made some changes to configuration.php to get it to connect to my database.  When I try to visit the site I get this error:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\libraries\joomla\error\exception.php on line 117

My php memory_limit is 512MB and for a small few page joomla site, there's no reason that I'm using this much memory.

I've found that the problem occurs here:

```
$menu  =& JSite::getMenu(true);
```

when getMenu is called, if I put an echo statement in this function in JMenu:

```
function &getInstance($client, $options = array())
```

it gets printed over and over which makes me think somehow an infinite loop is happening but I'm not sure why...

Comment: You could enable [XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/), as he would output a stacktrace (name of called functions) and its related memory values. See [this page](http://docs.joomla.org/Setting_up_your_workstation_for_Joomla!_development#Test_XDebug_Installation) for install instructions.

Comment: I ended up using some echo statements to show, edited original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just magically started working.  I think it had something to do with the mod_rewrite setting but I can't prove it...

Answer (score 0):

Which version of joomla do you use?

I read something about this error appearing by using specific themes. Try to uninstall themes or to use the standard theme. Does it now work? If it works the error must be in the theme. So analyze it. Otherwise post it here ;-)

Comment: I'm using Joomla 1.5.  It works on the website, just not locally.  By themes do you mean templates?

Comment: yes, templates. Did you also tried to install a fresh version of joomla on your xampp?

Comment: The site is using one of the default templates (milkyway) so it can't be that.  From my understanding, you don't "INSTALL" a version of joomla on your xampp.  If I want to make a new site, I download joomla and put the files in a directory and it works once I run the installer, but for a site that's already made, it has it's own joomla installation built in, right?

Comment: That's correct. You download the files and start the setup file which leads you through the installation. Have you did this? Was this successful?

Comment: When I want to make a new site, I download the files and start the setup file which leads me through the installation.  When I want to use an existing site, if I run the setup file again won't it just erase my site?